# Create columns after fill table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a long query who retrieves a long list of items, to achieve this I needed to do my query dynamically:

Relevant code:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
  DECLARE @DList TABLE
            (
                            [ProjectKey]         INT
                           , [DesignKey]          INT
                          ...
            )

            DECLARE @ExistDesignKey BIT = (SELECT TOP 1
                               1
                               FROM [#SearchKeys]);

                                   INSERT INTO @DList
                 SELECT
                       [p].[ProjectKey]
                     , [pd].[DesignKey]
                     ...

                WHERE ...

   ';


            DECLARE @Select NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' SELECT
                    *
                    FROM @DList
               ORDER BY
                    '+@CurrentSortBy+'
                    , [Design Name]
                    , [DesignTypeName]
                    , [DesignNumber]
                    , [RevisionNumber]
                            ';
            DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = @Sql + @Select
```

So, as you can see, I create table with multiple columns, then I insert data into it.

That I want to do is to add two more columns to this Table, but I need DesignKey column rows for query.

New colums:

```
DECLARE @CustomerAndContactsTable AS TABLE
(
                                   [CustomerName]         VARCHAR(1000)
                                 , [ContactName]          VARCHAR(1000)
                                 , [CommunicationType]    VARCHAR(255)
                                 , [CommunicationAddress] VARCHAR(1000)
)

INSERT INTO @CustomerAndContactsTable
      SELECT
            [CU].[Name]
          , CONCAT([C].[FirstName] , ' ' , [C].[LastName])
          , [CT].[DeviceType]
          , [COM].[Address]
            FROM [DesignCustomer] AS [DC]
                INNER JOIN [Customer] AS [CU] ON [DC].[CustomerKey] = [CU].[CustomerKey]
                INNER JOIN [CustomerContact] AS [CC] ON [DC].[CustomerKey] = [CC].[CustomerKey]
                INNER JOIN [Contact] AS [C] ON [CC].[ContactKey] = [C].[ContactKey]
                INNER JOIN [Communication] AS [COM] ON [c].[ContactGuid] = [com].[ComGuid]
                INNER JOIN [ComType] AS [CT] ON [COM].[ComTypeKey] = [CT].[ComTypeKey]
            WHERE [DesignKey] =  --need designkey of row 
                AND [c].[IsPrincipal] = 1
                AND [COM].[ComTypeKey] IN(1 , 2 , 3 , 4)
                AND [DC].[Contracted] = 1

SELECT TOP 1
      [CustomerName]
    , CONCAT([ContactName] , ' Contact: ' , STUFF(
      (SELECT
            ', '+CONCAT([CommunicationType] , ': ' , [CommunicationAddress])
            FROM @CustomerAndContactsTable FOR XML PATH('')
      ) , 1 , 1 , '')) AS [PrincipalContact]
      FROM @CustomerAndContactsTable
      GROUP BY
             [CustomerName]
            , [ContactName]
            , [CommunicationType]
            , [CommunicationAddress]
```

I want to set this two columns `CustomerName` and `PrincipalContact`, but as you can see I need to use `designkey`  in @`CustomerAndContactsTable` table

How can I iterate into @`DList` once it have `DesignKey` values and use to insert another two columns?

Comment: It would be much more helpful, and you'll probably get a lot more responses, if you trimmed the code to the minimal needed to highlight your problem. Do you really need to show 20+ columns and joins of 5+ tables?

Comment: You're right, I updated my question @Greg

Comment: What exactly is the question?   Just add the new columns into your dynamic statements the way you did in the second code block.   I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: But how? If I have values into another table? @TabAlleman